# Permission for services

Tags: android, service

i have a service in one application and i want to use that service in one more application.so inoder to start or stop or bind with the service should i need to set any permission?if yes what are the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following url ... Hopefully it will be useful for you

[Basic of Android](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/)

Answer (score 0):

@Durga
first of all you have to make one services class for example TestService.java

```
(1)TestServices.java
```

now you have to require for permission in menifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.AutoStart" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

now you have to call your services in any activity.

in my case i used receiver to start services in when device is first Boot.