# Crash on sending intent with Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: android, android-x86

I'm sending a share intent with the Glaxy Tab 3 (Intel x86 cpu).
But this result in a crash.

This is the log from the system

```
03

-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Build: samsung/santos10wifixx/santos10wifi:4.2.2/JDQ39/P5210XXUAMG7:user/release-keys
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Hardware: clovertrail
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Revision: 8
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Bootloader: P5210XXUAMG7
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Radio: unknown
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.34-1142284 (dpi@DELL149) (gcc version 4.6 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 18 22:33:33 KST 2013
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifixx/santos10wifi:4.2.2/JDQ39/P5210XXUAMG7:user/release-keys'
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): Revision: '8'
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): pid: 20644, tid: 20644, name: il.co.yes.yesgo  >>> il.co.yes.yesgo <<<
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 4000e370
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     eax 4003bec8  ebx 40028ff4  ecx 00000000  edx 00000001
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     esi 00000016  edi 00000067
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     eip 4000e370  ebp 00000004  esp bf8c058c  flags 00010212
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): backtrace:
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     #00  pc 0000a370  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     #01  pc 000089b4  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     #02  pc 0000040c  [vdso]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): stack:
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c054c  bf8c0680  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0550  bf8c0680  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0554  00000001  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0558  40022baf  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c055c  4001803e  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0560  00000001  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0564  bf8c0578  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0568  00000000  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c056c  410cbbd1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0570  00000003  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0574  00000003  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0578  bf8c05a0  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c057c  00000001  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0580  40021f28  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0584  00000005  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0588  bf8c0680  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     #00  bf8c058c  4000a3bf  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0590  00000001  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0594  4000a3a6  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c0598  40028ff4  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c059c  4000c9b4  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     #01  bf8c05a0  00000067  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05a4  bf8c05e8  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05a8  00000001  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05ac  00000004  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05b0  40021ecf  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05b4  4000e370  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05b8  00000002  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05bc  000050a4  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05c0  bf8c05ec  [stack]
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05c4  00000008  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05c8  0000002e  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05cc  00000073  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05d0  60f70099  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@il.co.yes.yesgo-2.apk@classes.dex
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05d4  00000004  
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05d8  40021f28  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          bf8c05dc  40021ecf  /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):          ........  ........
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): memory map around fault addr 4000e370:
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     40003000-40004000 /system/bin/app_process
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     40004000-40028000 /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321):     40028000-40029000 /system/bin/linker
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): processName:il.co.yes.yesgo
03-13 16:08:19.738: D/CrashAnrDetector(2321): broadcastEvent : il.co.yes.yesgo SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
03-13 16:08:19.768: W/ContextImpl(2321): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1375 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:291 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102
```

Intent code

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String mUrl;
            try {
                mUrl = URLEncoder.encode(media.getWebLink(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                mUrl = media.getWebLink();
            }
            String m = TvinciSDK.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.share_message__f_s, 
                    TvinciSDK.getSessionManager().getFirstName(),
                    media.getName(),
                    media.getWebLink());
//          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "text");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, m);
//          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, message);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            Context context =  v.getContext();
            if (context != null) {
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, context.getString(R.string.yesshare_title, title));
                chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
```

Comment: Does it work with other device (virtual or not), or is it only with Galaxy Tab 3?

Comment: And publish your code please...

Comment: Yes, it works on both the galaxy s3 and the galaxy tab 2

Comment: Looks like a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584801/permission-in-calling-service-from-another-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Well it appears this has to do with hardware acceleration on intel x86 devices.

As soon as I removed this filed from my manifest (not just settings it to false, but removing it) , it don't crash any more.

Comment: I  am facing the same issue in note 2. I could not get the solution. Can help me on this ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is by context. It is necessary to refer to the activity that implements the share button. `Context context = this`

Comment: The context of a view is derived from its activity. Therefor it's totally ok to use the context of the view. Moreover if i were using the wrong context it wouldn't work anywhere not only on the tab 3